# How to secure automatic SSH connection

Tags: linux, security, ssh, raspberry-pi

I have Raspberry PI 3 which has 4G modem dongle attached to it. It works autonomously and every one in a while has to connect to my server via ssh. This is done by service script either with password or with key authentication which both require password/passphrase to be present in a script or in a file. The problem is that anyone can take out RPi SD card and take that password/passphrase or id_rsa key itself.
Are there any secure solutions for this?

Comment: In a similar scenario I handled this by allowing the remote device to make an SSH connection to a gateway, and then a server connected to the gateway would connect *back* to the remote device using `ssh -R...`. Then, all important communication was done through the tunnel on the second connection. If a device didn't "call in" according to its schedule, I wouldn't establish the second tunnel, and would investigate instead. If you have multiple devices, make sure you have a unique SSH key for each, so it can be expired.

Comment: That said, I've voted to close this question because it's a request for a recommendation for a solution, rather than for assistance with your own code. This makes the question off-topic for StackOverflow. You might want to try http://ServerFault.com or https://security.stackexchange.com/ instead.

Comment: What is you gateway? Basically my server to which RPi connects is kind of gateway itself. RPi executed ssh  -R reverse forward command. It is done to access RPi remotely, because it doe not accept any inbound traffic.